# Should every url from urls.py in django have it's own method to respond the request?

Tags: python, django

My test site has several search pages and each page contains it's own search form.
But some of these pages are very identical and their displaying functions in **views.py** are very similar.

For example:

```
@csrf_exempt
def rooms(request):
    submited = False
    search_option = 'None'
    search_param = 'None'
    data = []
    query = ''

    try:
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='****', host='127.0.0.1', database='lessons')
        cursor = cnx.cursor()

        if not submited:
            query = "SELECT * FROM Rooms;"
            cursor.execute(query)
            data = cursor.fetchall()

        if request.method == 'POST':
            submited = True
            if request.POST['search_option'] != "" and request.POST['search_param'] != "":
                search_option = request.POST['search_option']
                search_param = request.POST['search_param']
                query = "SELECT * FROM Rooms WHERE " + search_option + " = " + search_param + ';'
                cursor.execute(query)
                data = cursor.fetchall()

    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            print("Database does not exist")
        else:
            print(err)

    return render(request, "rooms.html",
                  {"page_name": "Rooms", "search_option": search_option, "search_param": search_param,
                   "submited": submited, "dbdata": data, "query": query})

@csrf_exempt
def teachers(request):
    submited = False
    search_option = 'None'
    search_param = 'None'
    data = []

    try:
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='****', host='127.0.0.1', database='lessons')
        cursor = cnx.cursor()

        if submited == False:
            query = "SELECT * FROM Teachers;"
            cursor.execute(query)
            data = cursor.fetchall()

        if request.method == 'POST':
            submited = True
            if 'search_option' in request.POST and 'search_param' in request.POST:
                search_option = request.POST['search_option']
                search_param = request.POST['search_param']
                query = "SELECT * FROM Teachers WHERE " + search_option + " = '" + search_param + "';"
                cursor.execute(query)
                data = cursor.fetchall()

    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            print("Database does not exist")
        else:
            print(err)

    return render(request, "teachers.html",
                  {"page_name": "Teachers", "search_option": search_option, "search_param": search_param,
                   "submited": submited, "dbdata": data, "query": query})
```

I was wondering how could I make several similar search urls (with some very small changes, in my case it's a different initial SQL-Query to display the general results) refer to one function (maybe due some if statement decide which page to display) rather than to several quite identical and avoid code repetition.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'rooms', 'lessons.views.rooms', name='rooms'),
                       url(r'teachers', 'lessons.views.teachers', name='teachers'),
                       url(r'subjects', 'lessons.views.subjects', name='subjects'))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using raw SQL rather than model and ORM calls?

Comment: @DanielRoseman ,  It's just a task from our teacher. The next work will involve ORM. I suppose this lab is supposed to show us the advantages of using ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same view function, let's say `lessons.views.generic_view`, from each url and you can discriminate based on view's name like this:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve

def generic_view(request):
    view_name = resolve(request.path).view_name
    if view_name == 'teachers':
         ...
```

Your sample `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'rooms', 'lessons.views.generic_view', name='rooms'),
    url(r'teachers', 'lessons.views.generic_view', name='teachers'),
    url(r'subjects', 'lessons.views.generic_view', name='subjects')
)
```

Comment: I'd say this violates PEP-20, line two. There is a more explicit path to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The request router configuration (which is what you could call `urls.py`) is exactly for the purpose of keeping request mapping and view code separate. You can also use it for view re-use.

If you check some of django's own examples for [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/), you will find:

```
(r'^about/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html"))
```

Which is more or less exactly what you are suggesting: Re-use the same view code for different types of URLs. You can emulate it for normal views, too:

```
def my_view(request, param=None):
   [...]

from functools import partial

url(r'^my_view0/', partial(views.my_view, param=0)),
url(r'^my_view1/', partial(views.my_view, param=1))
```